# How to save a worksheet as another workbook with a dynamic name?

Tags: excel, vba

I understand how to save a worksheet as a new workbook, but how do I can specify the name dynamically?
I've tried both `Save As` and `Save` as filename but I can't figure out how to put a variable into the name successfully.

```
Sub sheetCopy()

   Dim wbS As Workbook, wbT As Workbook
   Dim wsS As Worksheet, wsT As Worksheet
   Dim title As String

   title = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("IR General Info").Range("B2").Text

   Set wbS = ThisWorkbook 'workbook that holds this code
   Set wsS = wbS.Worksheets("Bulk Upload")

   wsS.Copy
   Set wbT = ActiveWorkbook 'assign reference asap

   Set wsT = wbT.Worksheets("Bulk Upload")
   wsT.Name = "Exported_BulkUpload" 'rename sheet

   wbT.SaveAs wbS.Path & "\" & title & ".xlsx"

End Sub
```

So If I make title something like "boo" with quotes - this code works. But how do I make it change based on the variable title?

Comment: have you stepped through your code using `F8`? Does a value get assigned to `title`?

Comment: "*So If I make title something like "boo" with quotes - this code works. But how do I make it change based on the variable title?*" You're going to have to clarify that. It works when the value of `title` is `"boo"` but not when... what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub sheetCopy()

   Dim wbS As Workbook, wbT As Workbook
   Dim wsS As Worksheet, wsT As Worksheet
   Dim title As String

   title = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("IR General Info").Range("B2").Text

   '<<step through the macro and once you have gone past this point do Ctl+G to get the immediate window then type ?title in it and press enter. Or just hover your mouse over title in this script - has a value been assigned to it?   

   '<<the following line is not required - ThisWorkbook object is sufficient:
   'Set wbS = ThisWorkbook 'workbook that holds this code

   Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Bulk Upload")

   wsS.Copy  '<<I've changed below here so it is saved straight away
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & title & ".xlsx"
   Set wbT = excel.workbooks(title & ".xlsx") 'assign reference 

   Set wsT = wbT.Worksheets("Bulk Upload")
   wsT.Name = "Exported_BulkUpload" 'rename sheet


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, your code is more concise. Furthermore, you helped me realize that the reason it didn't work was because of variable "title" had back slashes in it (invalid file name). So thanks!

Comment: (well - if my answer helped answer the question you could always mark it correct...or just up-vote it if you're not feeling that generous!)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried assigning the `title` variable to `Range("B2").Value` instead of `Range("B2").Text` ?

If the files are in the same folder, you might be able to use `wbT.SaveAs FileName:=title` instead

Comment: Yes, I've tried text and value to no avail. Unfortunately the files might not be in the same folder.