# Copy and Rename dynamic excel workbooks save with pdf and txt documents

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, copy, txt

Hi I have quite a number of excel workbooks with pdf and txt documents in one folder and want to save them in a new folder (folder name same as excel workbook) with pdf and txt documents only but not with excel.

The below code can only copy the exists folder with the specific folder name:

```
Sub FSOCopyFolder()

Dim fso As Object

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

fso.CopyFolder "C:\User\A", "C:\User\A" 'Dst folder exists
fso.CopyFolder "C:\User\A", "C:\User\A" 'DstNew folder is created

End Sub
```

I would like to save dynamic folders according to the dynamic excel file names with pdf and txt documents only.

EG. Folder A-111 has A-111.xlsm, A-111.pdf and A-111.txt and want to copy A-111.pdf and A-111.txt documents in a new destination with a new folder.

Folder B-111 has B-111.xlsm, B-111.pdf and B-111.txt and want to copy B-111.pdf and B-111.txt documents in a new destination with a new folder etc

Comment: This post might help ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959234/how-to-save-a-worksheet-as-another-workbook-with-a-dynamic-name

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub distributeFile()
Dim FileName As String
Dim fs As Object

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Path
FileName = Dir([put here the full path where the files are] & "\*.xlsm")

Do While FileName <> ""
Dim newFolderName As String, fileBaseName
    fileBaseName = fs.getbasename(FileName)
    newFolderName = "C:\User\New\" & fileBaseName & "\"
    If fs.FileExists(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & fileBaseName & ".pdf") Then
        If Not fs.FolderExists(newFolderName) Then fs.CreateFolder (newFolderName)
        fs.movefile ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & fileBaseName & ".pdf", newFolderName
    End If
    If fs.FileExists(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & fileBaseName & ".txt") Then
        If Not fs.FolderExists(newFolderName) Then fs.CreateFolder (newFolderName)
        fs.movefile ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & fileBaseName & ".txt", newFolderName
    End If
    FileName = Dir()
Loop
Set fs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you
with this -> FileName = Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\*.xlsm") I have got error -> Bad file name or number.

Also my new dest location is C:\User\New\ + (then every new folders)
so how to edit this part fs.movefile ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & fileBaseName & ".pdf", newFolderName

Thanks heaps for your help

Comment: Can you `Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Path`? I guess there's a problem there.  I also changed the initialization of the variable `newFolderName = "C:\User\New\" & fileBaseName & "\"`

Comment: I put it here -> 
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.path
FileName = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\*.xlsm" -> and it does shows a link but if i put debug after FileName code doesnt show up coz theres the Bad file name error.

Comment: I edited the line `FileName = Dir([put here the full path where the files are] & "\*.xlsm")`. Replace the brackets with the string of the directory full path where are your files, like for example "C:\User\Old\".

Comment: it doesnt show up the error message anymore. Thanks. But still cant copy the files to the new folder. wondering would it be my .pdf and .txt file name is dynamic? eg. 1111_2222-ABCD.pdf   eg. 2222_3333-TEST.pdf    eg. 1111_2222-ABCD.txt    eg. 2222_3333-TEST.txt

Comment: The procedure moves only the files with the same basenames as the *.xlsm in the directory: if there's 1111_2222-ABCD.xlsm, then 1111_2222-ABCD.pdf and 1111_2222-ABCD.txt are moved into the directory C:\User\New\1111_2222-ABCD; otherwise they are not.

Comment: How to edit the code to get the different pdf documents copy to the related folder?

Comment: Sorry but I must have misunderstood you requirements:
1 - are all your files (xlsm, pdf, txt) in only one folder, and you want them to be distributed?
2 - or are your files in separate folders?
Maybe you could edit your question.

Comment: so sorry my bad. eg. C:\user\Test\1111_2222 -> 1st folder contains (1111_2222.xlsm, 1111_2222.png, 1111_2222-ABCD.pdf, 1111_2222-EFGH.pdf, 1111_2222-VXYZ.txt). C:\user\Test\2222_3333 -> 2nd folder contains (2222_3333.xlsm, 2222_3333.png, 2222_3333-ABCD.pdf, 2222_3333-EFGH.pdf, 2222_3333-TUVX.txt) etc. Want to copy 1st folder all documents except xlsm to C:\user\NewFile\1111_2222.  2nd folder copy to C:\user\NewFile\2222_3333. etc Thanks